# Power friendly home router, firewall, IDS/IPS setup?

Tags: firewalls, ids

For those that like to manage their own firewall and run IDS/IPS on their home networks, I'm curious - what are you using and is it power friendly?

I used to have a shelf full systems doing various things, but moving a lot had me trim down and I'm currently just using an off the shelf home wifi router, and need something with more power.  Ideally running Linux, would like to run Suricata or Snort on it, maybe in IDS mode.  And with logging to a database - that could offload that to another machine.

Comment: What services are you running that you would need an IDS setup?

Comment: IDS is worthwhile for anyone in IT Security, or even in IT - you can watch for odd traffic - which may help you in your day job; you are more likely to spot anomalies; and you are bound to have something sensitive on your network you want to protect.

Answer (score 3):

Have in the past used a [MikroTik](http://www.mikrotik.com/) as router and firewall, and a [Mini-ITX](http://www.mini-itx.com/) running Snort and some more intelligent filtering than the basic MikroTik box. Don't know what the total power consumption was, but they didn't even get warm.

Easy to setup and they just work:-)

Comment: +1 for MikroTik - looks pretty good. Much cheaper than buying a Soekris box or a build your own VIA system.

Comment: Yeah - I hadn't heard of them until @RoryMcCune introduced me to them - Cisco-ish interface and commands, very simple to configure and quite fully featured little boxen.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check for [Endian firewall community version](http://www.endian.com/community/overview/), which as know is free and can be run in virtual machine.

Comment: Hi webcore - welcome to Security.SE. Once you have earned more rep you will be able to comment on other posts, but your 1st paragraph doesn't answer the question at all - the OP is not asking about mangle or the functionality so I have edited it out. For your 2nd paragraph, can you explain why running a virtual machine is power-friendly? Until you do, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Power friendly **and** powerful are hard to come by in cheap packages. It really depends on traffic workload. You may easily get away with some high end router (say ~$100) with OpenWRT. Check OpenWRT page for what models are supported. Get one with USB if you want to store more data on board or have a NAS handy.

The other option has already been mentioned - MikroTik. But that is a little bit more expensive and I have bad experience with MikroTik OS heavy customisation. It is some linux but it's highly proprietaty and there aren't many packages for it (ymmv).

And then, of course, there's [Turris Lite](https://lite.turris.cz/en/). If you're feeling hacky, you may even build one of your own. The hardware is open source and it runs OpenWRT :)